# Creating grid with GTK buttons

Tags: c, gtk

I want to create a grid with buttons. When a button is clicked I want it to change color, and 0 or 1 get stored in an array depending on the current state of the button.

Now I do this by creating the buttons with two for loops (rows, and columns).
Inside the for loops;

```
/*Create an ID number for the button being created*/
btn_nr ++;
char btn_nr_str[3];
sprintf(btn_nr_str,"%d",btn_nr); //convert nr to string

/*Create button*/
button = gtk_button_new();

/* When the button is clicked, we call the "callback" function
 * with a pointer to the ID */
gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (button), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (callback)(gpointer) btn_nr_str);

/* Insert button into the table */
gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(table), button, col, col+1, row, row+1);
gtk_widget_show (button);
```

The callback function;

```
void callback( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer nr)
{
    GdkColor buttonColor;
    gdk_color_parse ("black", &buttonColor);
    gtk_widget_modify_bg ( GTK_WIDGET(widget), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &buttonColor);
    g_print ("Hello again - %s was pressed\n", (char *) nr);
}
```

The buttons are created like wanted, and when clicked they turn black.
However, all buttons print the last created button's ID.

How do I pass the right ID on?

Comment: You have a copy&paste problem in `gtk_signal_connect` call (a missing comma). Please, double check before posting code because it is going to create misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing a local array (`btn_nr_str`) from outside (the callback) its scope (the `for` cycle). The idea is correct (using `user_data`) but the implementation is not.

For your specific case, you can use the [type conversion macros](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html) provided by `GLib`. They are meant for exactly this purpose:

```
/* In the for cycle */
g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(callback), GINT_TO_POINTER(btn_nr);

/* In the callback */
gint btn_nr = GPOINTER_TO_INT(user_data);
```

P.S.: `gtk_signal_connect` has been deprecated years ago.